# Documenting constructor functions without new

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have a constructor function, `Foo`, that I want my users to call without `new`. For example,

```
const myFoo = Foo('bar');
```

for `Foo` defined as,

```
function Foo(bar) {
  if(!this) { return new Foo(bar); }
  foo.bar = bar;
  return this;
}
```

How do I document this with JSDoc3? If I use `@class` (or `@constructor`) with the default template, the output always uses `new Foo(bar)`. If I document `Foo` as just a `@function`, none of its instance methods or properties show up, just the function itself.

Is there a way to separate the class definition from the constructor function? Or configure the output to not specify `new` in the constructor? `@lends` and `@constructs` looks to address a similar need, but for the constructor and instance methods defined in an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `@hideconstructor` ? , like for example:

/**
some description
@class
@hideconstructor
*/
function Foo()...

Nevertheless this will fail in  type-checking validation with typescript via jsdoc. IN that case, if you don't want your users never to use `new` then you should document the class as `ClassFoo` with `@hideconstructor` and separately the function Foo that `@returns {ClassFoo}`